# Is there a way to isolate the NGXS store in a llibrary?

Tags: angular, ngxs

we are using the [NGXS](https://www.ngxs.io/) store in our application (=APP1):

```
NgxsModule.forRoot()
```

Now we separated part of that application into a library component / separate npm package (=LIB). This component also uses NGXS to handle its state and it uses the:

```
NgxsModule.forFeature()
```

to initialize its own custom states.

So far so good, but now we want to include LIB into another application (=APP2) which does not use NGXS and therefore does not use the:

```
NgxsModule.forRoot()
```

Questions is: How to include LIB in APP2 without having APP2 need to know that there is a NGX store in LIB. It should be transparent to APP2.

Thanks in advance for any help and ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to split your library using signposts. Here's a great article that will put you on the right path:

https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/improve-spa-performance-by-splitting-your-angular-libraries-in-multiple-chunks-8c68103692d0

Answer (score 0):

For my use case I could handle it this way:

In the library I export two modules:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [NgxsModule.forFeature([...])
})
export class FeatureModule{}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    FeatureModule,
    NgxsModule.forRoot()
  ]
})
export class RootModule {}
```

We document the RootModule for others users and used the FeatureModule by out app.